# Default and individual Google docs settings in workspaces (except for templates)

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace

I need support with the usage of Google Docs: I want all the docs every employee in our agency creates be uniform in terms of font and headline settings. We are working with templates in our google workspace, but the default way people open new docs is not the template.
They just open a new doc and it's understandable because that's one click less. So it would be great if the general docs setting could be set once and are valid for all the users… Any expertise here in the group? Thx, Timm

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible at the moment. The Google Docs default settings cannot be changed in any possible way. Using templates would be the best option so that your users can just create a copy of the documents and keep working on the copies.

What you can do to make it easier for them to open the templates is to create bookmarks on their browser (only works in Chrome) so that they have a bookmarks folder with all the templates on it, so it is easier for them to access everything. For this you can use this [Chrome policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanaged-bookmarks) in the Admin console to add control the managed bookmarks folder.

Comment: Thx for explaining, Fernando Lara!